# Apply sum to chunks of a vector in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector `v` containing the number of elements I need to add up from another vector `w`. How can I do this in R?

Example

```
v = c(4,0,3,3,0,0)
w = rexp(10,1)
```

So, I need a new vector containing `c(w[1]+w[2]+w[3]+w[4],0,w[5]+w[6]+w[7],w[8]+w[9]+w[10],0,0)`. How can I construct such vector? I thought of using `apply` but I cannot see how to do it. A `for` loop could also work, but there is a problem with the zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use  `rep` on the sequence of 'v' to create a grouping variable, get the `sum` of 'w' with `tapply` using the grouping variable and append the 0's based on the position of '0' in 'v'

```
r1 <- unname(tapply(w, rep(seq_along(v), v), FUN = sum))
i1 <- which(v==0)-1
for(i in seq_along(i1)) r1 <- append(r1, 0, after = i1[i])
r1
#[1] 2.951259 0.000000 2.982644 4.233564 0.000000 0.000000
```

Comment: What if v contains other zeroes in the middle? Sorry for not specifying this. I guess replacing the values in a zero vector with `ifelse` would work, right?

Comment: @Trilobite  It is not clear where you want to append then because the `sum` of some numbers is always a single number

Comment: @Trilobite  Could you please update the question as I am not finding where the 0's will occupy with the summarised data

Comment: @akrun it is already updated `v = c(4,0,3,3,0,0)` and `w = rexp(10,1)`. I need a new vector containing `c(w[1]+w[2]+w[3]+w[4],0,w[5]+w[6]+w[7],w[8]+w[9]+w[10],0,0)`.

Comment: @Trilobite  Updated the post